# Want to calculate the price for each room in codeigniter3

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, price

I created a booking system for a homestay website and i'm using codeigniter3 for this project but the client gave me some complex conditions to implement with the booking and need to calculate the price room wise and in final a total of these rooms.

I'm very confuse to write code for following case where I need to show price for each room according to the following condition:

I stored data as in misc. array in session

For room

```
[selectedRoom] => Array
        (
            [0] => Mud House (Neel Kutir)
            [1] => Mud House (Lal Kutir)
            [2] => Standard AC Room
            [3] => Deluxe AC Room
        )
```

For adults (before the underscore it is room name & after the underscore, it is the adult count)

```
[adults] => Array
        (
            [0] => Mud House (Neel Kutir)_1
            [1] => Mud House (Lal Kutir)_1
            [2] => Standard AC Room_1
            [3] => Deluxe AC Room_1
        )
```

in this following array, i stored the number of nights

```
[dateRange] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2023-12-29,
            [1] => 2023-12-30,
            [2] => 2023-12-31
        )
```

In this following array i stored data as

format of the data is
{room name}*{total number of kids}*{kids count serial wise}_{age group like before slash it is starting year & after slash it is ending year}

```
[kids_age] => Array
        (
            [0] => Mud House (Neel Kutir)_2_1_5/8
            [1] => Mud House (Neel Kutir)_2_2_8/12
            [2] => Mud House (Lal Kutir)_2_1_1/4
            [3] => Mud House (Lal Kutir)_2_2_8/12
            [4] => Standard AC Room_2_1_1/4
            [5] => Standard AC Room_2_2_5/8
            [6] => Deluxe AC Room_2_1_8/12
            [7] => Deluxe AC Room_2_2_5/8
        )
```

following are the conditions that need to be implemented

> if room is "Mud House (Neel Kutir)" or "Mud House (Neel Kutir)" then
> price calculation will be like

**if booking is for 1 night**

```
for adult price will be like 
adult  =  1850  (for  1 Night  Per  Person )
kids = 1850 (for  1 Night  Per  Person ) 
and 
if kid age is (between 1 to 4 years then the price is 0)
or if kid age is (between 5 to 8 years then the price is 50% of  1850)
or if kid age is (between 8 to 12 years then the price is 75% of  1850)
or if kid age is (above 12 years then the price is 1850)
```

**if booking is for 2 nights**
f

```
or adult price will be like 
adult  =  1500  (for  2 Nights  Per  Person )
kids = 1500 (for  2 Nights Per  Person ) 
and 
if kid age is (between 1 to 4 years then the price is 0)
or if kid age is (between 5 to 8 years then the price is 50% of  1500)
or if kid age is (between 8 to 12 years then the price is 75% of  1500)
or if kid age is (above 12 years then the price is 1850)
```

**if booking is for 3 nights or above**
for

```
adult price will be like 
adult  =  1350  (for  3 Nights or above  Per  Person )
kids = 1350 (for  3 Nights or above Per  Person ) 
and 
if kid age is (between 1 to 4 years then the price is 0)
or if kid age is (between 5 to 8 years then the price is 50% of  1350)
or if kid age is (between 8 to 12 years then the price is 75% of  1350)
or if kid age is (above 12 years then the price is 1350)
```

> if room is "Standard AC Room" then price calculation will be like

**if booking is for 1 night**

```
for adult price will be like 
adult  =  2050  (for  1 Night  Per  Person )
kids = 2050 (for  1 Night  Per  Person ) 
and 
if kid age is (between 1 to 4 years then the price is 0)
or if kid age is (between 5 to 8 years then the price is 50% of  2050)
or if kid age is (between 8 to 12 years then the price is 75% of  2050)
or if kid age is (above 12 years then the price is 2050)
```

**if booking is for 2 nights**

```
for adult price will be like 
adult  =  1700  (for  2 Nights  Per  Person )
kids = 1700 (for  2 Nights Per  Person ) 
and 
if kid age is (between 1 to 4 years then the price is 0)
or if kid age is (between 5 to 8 years then the price is 50% of  1700)
or if kid age is (between 8 to 12 years then the price is 75% of  1700)
or if kid age is (above 12 years then the price is 1700)
```

**if booking is for 3 nights or above**

```
for adult price will be like 
adult  =  1550  (for  3 Nights or above  Per  Person )
kids = 1550 (for  3 Nights or above Per  Person ) 
and 
if kid age is (between 1 to 4 years then the price is 0)
or if kid age is (between 5 to 8 years then the price is 50% of  1550)
or if kid age is (between 8 to 12 years then the price is 75% of  1550)
or if kid age is (above 12 years then the price is 1550)
```

> if room is "Deluxe AC Room" then price calculation will be like

**if booking is for 1 night**

```
for adult price will be like 
adult  =  3350  (for  1 Night  Per  Person )
kids = 3350 (for  1 Night  Per  Person ) 
and 
if kid age is (between 1 to 4 years then the price is 0)
or if kid age is (between 5 to 8 years then the price is 50% of  3350)
or if kid age is (between 8 to 12 years then the price is 75% of  3350)
or if kid age is (above 12 years then the price is 3350)
```

**if booking is for 2 nights**

```
for adult price will be like 
adult  =  3000  (for  2 Nights  Per  Person )
kids = 3000 (for  2 Nights Per  Person ) 
and 
if kid age is (between 1 to 4 years then the price is 0)
or if kid age is (between 5 to 8 years then the price is 50% of  3000)
or if kid age is (between 8 to 12 years then the price is 75% of  3000)
or if kid age is (above 12 years then the price is 3000)
```

**if booking is for 3 nights or above**

```
for adult price will be like 
adult  =  2850  (for  3 Nights or above  Per  Person )
kids = 2850 (for  3 Nights or above Per  Person ) 
and 
if kid age is (between 1 to 4 years then the price is 0)
or if kid age is (between 5 to 8 years then the price is 50% of  2850)
or if kid age is (between 8 to 12 years then the price is 75% of  2850)
or if kid age is (above 12 years then the price is 2850)
```

Answer (score 1):

Start by creating an array that groups the number of adults and the kids' ages per room:

```
foreach ($array['adults'] as $room_adults) {
    $room_adults_parts = explode('_', $room_adults);
    $guests_per_room[$room_adults_parts[0]]['adults'] = $room_adults_parts[1];
}

foreach ($array['kids_age'] as $room_kids_age) {
    $room_kids_age_parts = explode('_', $room_kids_age);
    $guests_per_room[$room_kids_age_parts[0]]['kids_age'][] = $room_kids_age_parts[3];
}
```

This gives a `$guests_per_room` array that looks like this:

```
array(4) {
  ["Mud House (Neel Kutir)"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["adults"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["kids_age"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(3) "5/8"
      [1]=>
      string(4) "8/12"
    }
  }
  ["Mud House (Lal Kutir)"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["adults"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["kids_age"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(3) "1/4"
      [1]=>
      string(4) "8/12"
    }
  }
  ["Standard AC Room"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["adults"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["kids_age"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(3) "1/4"
      [1]=>
      string(3) "5/8"
    }
  }
  ["Deluxe AC Room"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["adults"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["kids_age"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "8/12"
      [1]=>
      string(3) "5/8"
    }
  }
}
```

Then use this to calculate the total per room and final total:

```
$total = 0;
$number_of_nights = count($array['dateRange']);

foreach ($guests_per_room as $room => $guests) {

    // Start with the adult price for 1 night
    if (strpos($room, 'Mud House') === 0) {
        $adult_price = 1850;
    } else if ($room == 'Deluxe AC Room') {
        $adult_price = 3350;
    } else { // Standard AC Room
        $adult_price = 2050;
    }
    
    // If more than 1 night has been booked, subtract discount
    // (all rooms seem to have the same discount)
    if ($number_of_nights == 2) {
        $adult_price -= 350;
    } else if ($number_of_nights >= 3) {
        $adult_price -= 500;
    }

    $room_total = 0;
    
    // Add to the room total: the adult price multiplied by the number of adults
    if (isset($guests['adults'])) {
        $room_total += $adult_price * $guests['adults'];
    }
    
    // Add to the room total: the discounted price for each of the kids
    if (isset($guests['kids_age'])) {
        foreach ($guests['kids_age'] as $age) {
            if ($age == '5/8') {
                $room_total += 0.5 * $adult_price;
            } else if ($age == '8/12') {
                $room_total += 0.75 * $adult_price;
            } else if ($age != '1/4') { // Children older than 12
                $room_total += $adult_price;
            }
        }
    }    
    
    // Add the room total to the final total
    $total += $room_total;
    
    echo $room . ' total : ' . $room_total . "\n";
}

echo 'Final total : ' . $total;
```

It wasn't clear from your question whether the room price for multiple nights should also be multiplied with the number of nights. Adjust if needed.